# why getting session id not works on host?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

i used bellow syntax to get user session id and it works fine on my local machine my host is on shared server and when i upload it on my host, not works and return null value .

whats wrong?(my site is on mvc4 and .net 4.5)

i try this but return null on my host but they works on local

```
        try
        {
          var id1= HttpRequest.RequestContext.HttpContext.Session.SessionID;
          var id2= System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session.SessionID ;
        }
        catch (Exception err)
        {
              // error message
             // Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

        }
```

Comment: Where does this code live? In a controller action? Why are you using `HttpContext.Current` in an ASP.NET MVC application?

Comment: yes it is in my index action i'm new in mvc what is your solution to get session id in mvc?

Comment: @DarinDimitrov : **Why are you using `HttpContext.Current` in an ASP.NET MVC application?** can you tell the corrective action ?

Comment: @PKKG, yes, don't use it!

Comment: @DarinDimitrov : So, What's the corrective action ?